# Changing data using ICommand in MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, icommand

I have two windows: the parent and the child. There is the listbox in a parent window.

MainView:

```
<Button x:Name="btnUpdate" Content="Update"
                Command="{Binding Path=MyCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=lstPerson, Path=SelectedItem}" />

<ListBox x:Name="lstPerson" ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" />
```

I'm trying to change selected Person two-way update by using ICommand with parameter.

PersonViewModel:

```
        private ICommand myCommand;
        public ICommand MyCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (myCommand == null)
                {
                    myCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(CommandExecute, CanCommandExecute);
                }

                return myCommand;

            }

        }

        private void CommandExecute(object parameter)
        {

            var ew = new EditWindow()
                         {
                             DataContext =
                                 new EditViewModel()
                                     {
                                         Name = ((Person) parameter).Name, 
                                         Address = ((Person) parameter).Address
                                     }
                         };

            ew.Show();

        }
```

But selected instance of Person don't changed in listbox. What do I need to write to the xaml or PersonViewModel to make it working?

P.S.

Here is my Person

```
    public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string name;
        private string address;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return name;
            }
            set
            {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
        public string Address
        {
            get
            {
                return address;
            }
            set
            {
                address = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Address");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The parameter of your exceution command for the command is wrong. When your binding to `SelectedItem` of the list which is bound to an `ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel>`, the selected item will be of type `PersonViewModel`. Try initializing the `ICommand as`RelayCommand`and modify`CommandExecute(PersonViewModel person)` accordingly.

Secondly, the ICommand is defined on PersonViewModel, but the Command should be on the ViewModel which holds the `Persons` collection. So, either you move the Command or you define the command on PersonViewModel in a way that it modifies the particular ViewModel, it is on. Than you can spare the `CommandParameter`, but bind the command like this:

and make `CommandExecute` something like this:

```
private void CommandExecute(object parameter)
{
    // Modify this, ie. this.Name = something
}
```

Last thing, your ViewModel needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged as well and forward the model change notifications. Otherwise changes will not be reflected, unless the binding to an actual property updates it. For example, if you bind like this

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

the `Name` property on the ViewModel will be updated, but if you call

```
Name = "ChuckNorris"
```

in your `CommandExecute(..)` method, the UI won't be updated, because no change notfication is fired.

Comment: I do it!

1. Added in MainWindow.xaml:

    <ListBox x:Name="lstPerson" ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" SelectedItem={Binding SelectedPerson} />

2. Implemented INotifyPropertyChanged in PersonViewModel
3. Added the property SelectedPerson.

Thanks!